# Get the latest row of a table based on Latest Date and a distinct column in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

If I have the following SQL Table

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><td>colOne</td><td>colTwo</td><td>colThree</td><td>colDate</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>8</td><td>2014-02-05 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>6</td><td>8</td><td>2014-05-13 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>10</td><td>37</td><td>2014-07-25 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>12</td><td>184</td><td>2014-08-11 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>13</td><td>11</td><td>2014-08-12 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>41</td><td>14</td><td>2015-02-16 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>42</td><td>14</td><td>2015-02-16 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
</table>
```

And I want the following result, which is the latest record of each distinct colThree

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><td>colOne</td><td>colTwo</td><td>colThree</td><td>colDate</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>6</td><td>8</td><td>2014-05-13 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>10</td><td>37</td><td>2014-07-25 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>12</td><td>184</td><td>2014-08-11 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>13</td><td>11</td><td>2014-08-12 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>42</td><td>14</td><td>2015-02-16 00:00:00.000</td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the fastest way is :

```
select t.*
from t
where t.colDate = (select max(t2.colDate) from t t2 where t2.colThree = t.colThree);
```

The more canonical way using `row_number()` will do what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by colThree order by colDate desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In the event of ties, this will choose an arbitrary row.

Comment: I tried it, but it still returned more than one colThree records. It's supposed to only pick the latest colThree number record.

Comment: @cSharpDotNetGuy,  in the case of colThree = 14, where dates are the same, what would be the row you want returned? What is the criteria for your choice?

Comment: Alex, I want the latest colTwo in this case. Thank you, sir.

Comment: @cSharpDotNetGuy . . . The version with `row_number()` will only choose one row, guaranteed.